# How to test Spring controller using JUnit?

Tags: java, spring, junit

what is the flow to test spring controller using junit?

```
@Autowired
private PersonService personService;

@RequestMapping(value="/t2/{yy_id}/person", method=RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public PersonInfo[] getPersons() {

return personService.getPersons();
}
```

Please give some example.

Comment: What is what? I do not get your question...

Comment: It's just a method. Autowire the controller into a JUnit test and call the method on it. Mock the `PersonService` if you need to. This specific method might be too simple to test, though.

Comment: Are you trying to test the controller as a unit, or do you want to test it's integration into Spring as well (meaning you want to test the annotations as well)?

Answer (score 0):

You can autowire your controller into a JUnit test and run the test with SpringJUnit4ClassRunner. Of course you would need to create a test context to initialise spring context (e.g. instantiation of test personService and autowiring it) for the test. Following might be a good start. And the next steps would be to check spring docs about testing.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:test-spring-context.xml")
public class YourControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    private PersonController personController;

    @Test
    public void testGetPersons() {
        Assert.assertNotNull(personController.getPersons());
    }
}
```